# How do you push noncommited local development code up to a heroku server?

Tags: git, heroku

Currently when I run `git push test-server development:master` it is pushing up my github committed code.  What I want to do is to push up what I am working on locally in my `test` branch to run tests on the server without needing to commit that to github.  Is this possible?  If so, what command do I use?  Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git?

Comment: yep, I went there first but couldn't find the answer to this question.

Comment: Ah, ignore my answer (i will delete it) I didn't realise what heroku is, just thought it was a remote name....

Answer (score 0):

Pushing a branch to heroku is:

```
git push heroku your_branch:master
# Where [master:branch_name] = master is heroku, branch_name is your local branch
```

Pushing master itself is

```
git push heroku master
```

---

---

For instance recently I had a branch - `v311` I wanted to push to heroku but not be either merged (yet) into master or pushed to github and so I used:

```
git push heroku v311:master
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible. Just push your test branch to heroku.

```
$ git push test-server test:master
```